# Getting artifacts from GITLAB issue

Tags: gitlab-ci

Following the instructions:

- `jobs`: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html
- `jobs/…/artifacts`: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html

Issuing the commands:

```
CI_API_V4_URL="https://${GITLAB_HOST}/api/v4"
curl --silent --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${projectId}/jobs/${jobId}" | jq '{artifacts: .artifacts, artifacts_expire_at: .artifacts_expire_at}'
echo "-----"
curl --silent --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${projectId}/jobs/${jobId}/artifacts"
echo
echo "----"
```

Get the output:

```
{
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "file_type": "trace",
      "size": 3480918,
      "filename": "job.log",
      "file_format": null
    },
    {
      "file_type": "junit",
      "size": 189178,
      "filename": "junit.xml.gz",
      "file_format": "gzip"
    }
  ],
  "artifacts_expire_at": "2023-09-01T16:07:04.315Z"
}
----
{"message":"404 Not Found"}
----
```

Not sure why it is not finding the artifacts when I have just established they exist.

Added the artifact epirey date to show that they should be there.

Is there a call to validate that I have permission (I am pretty sure I do have permission but would be nice if there was an API to check).